# atkbd.c spamming the logs. How to get rid? what is this?

Tags: 10.04, dmesg, keycodes

On my Vostro 1000 notebook the following messages spam my dmesg:

```
[18678.728936] atkbd.c: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x8d on isa0060/serio0).
[18678.728941] atkbd.c: Use 'setkeycodes e00d <keycode>' to make it known.
[18679.831109] atkbd.c: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0x8d on isa0060/serio0).
[18679.831119] atkbd.c: Use 'setkeycodes e00d <keycode>' to make it known.
[18679.841607] atkbd.c: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x8d on isa0060/serio0).
[18679.841615] atkbd.c: Use 'setkeycodes e00d <keycode>' to make it known.
[18680.901733] atkbd.c: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0x8d on isa0060/serio0).
[18680.901744] atkbd.c: Use 'setkeycodes e00d <keycode>' to make it known.
[18680.911536] atkbd.c: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x8d on isa0060/serio0).
[18680.911546] atkbd.c: Use 'setkeycodes e00d <keycode>' to make it known.
```

It's most probably not from an actual key because it appears in regular intervals. First what is it? It could be my battery since it's nearly dead, as in loadable to 11 % of the initial capacity, but I have no evidence for that.

- What is this / how can I find out where this comes from?
- How can I get rid of it? Is there a 'dud' keycode?

When I assign a keycode with `sudo setkeycode e00d $(random keycode)` the key does actually get pressed. That makes it impossible to enter sudo password for example. So any 'real' keycode is not an option.

It hasn't been like that half a year ago. Even better than the dud keycode would be a real fix. It happens from **10.04 to 12.04** (before that I don't know).

---

I did read `zcat /usr/share/doc/udev/README.keymap.txt.gz |less` as suggested in the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting). `/lib/udev/findkeyboards && sudo /lib/udev/keymap -i input/event5` produces what appears to be newlines in rapid succession.

`sudo udevadm monitor` doesn't show the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

- Shut down your laptop.
- Unplug the power cord from your laptop, and unplug it also from the
  power outlet.
- Remove the battery from your laptop.
- Press and hold the *Power* button for 2 to 3 seconds.
- Repeat this 2 to 3 times.
- Reinstall the battery (at least 30 seconds should have gone by since you removed it).
- Plug the power cord back into your laptop (while leaving the power cord **unplugged** from the wall outlet)
- Press and hold the *Power* button again for 2 to 3 seconds.
- Repeat this 2 to 3 times.
- Plug the power cord into the wall outlet.
- Start your laptop

Comment: any explanation on why this should work? what does it do/reset?

Comment: It's actually a documented bug and workaround... Look [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=454131) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/549741).

Comment: This worked! I read about this when it first appeared some 3 years ago but couldn't find it now, thanks alot!

Comment: Glad to help :)